# Customizing Part in TOC

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, page-breaking, parts, emptypage

I am using `book` class and I want to create a part in TOC in the following way:

I want the part centred in the middle of the page and the chapters on the other page.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
    \makeatletter
    \def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\protect\numberline{\thepart}#1}
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \markboth{}{}%
    {\centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
       \huge\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart
       \par
       \vskip 20\p@
     \fi
     \Huge \bfseries #2\par}%
    \@endpart}
    \renewcommand\l@part[2]{%
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newpage 
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \begin{center}
    \def\numberline##1{%
    \Large Part~ ##1\newline
    }
    {\Huge #1}
    \end{center}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \newpage
     }
    \makeatother

    \begin{document}


    \tableofcontents

    \part{one}

    \chapter{one \\ two}
    \chapter{two}
    \chapter{three\\three\\three\\three\\three}
    \chapter{four}

    \part{two}

    \chapter{five}
    \chapter{six}
    \chapter{seven}
    \chapter{six}
    \chapter{seven}
    \chapter{six}
    \chapter{seven}
    \end{document}
```

I already put the part in a separated page, but I do not know why I can not change the font size of the TOC (i.e., why `\Large`, `\Huge` do not work in `\l@part`) and I can not put the empty page on this too (i.e., why `\thispagestyle{empty}` does not work in `\l@part`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the use of two sets of braces in the redefinition of `\numberline`.  The second set makes `\Large` local.

Also, I wasn't sure if the use of `\newline` was deliberate.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\makeatletter
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
  \refstepcounter{part}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\protect\numberline{\thepart}#1}
\else
  \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
\fi
\markboth{}{}%
{\centering
 \interlinepenalty \@M
 \normalfont
 \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
   \huge\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart
   \par
   \vskip 20\p@
 \fi
 \Huge \bfseries #2\par}%
\@endpart}
\renewcommand\l@part[2]{%
\newpage 
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
\def\numberline##1{{\Large Part~ ##1\\}}%
{\Huge #1}
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
\newpage
 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{one}

\chapter{one \\ two}
\chapter{two}
\chapter{three\\three\\three\\three\\three}
\chapter{four}

\part{two}

\chapter{five}
\chapter{six}
\chapter{seven}
\chapter{six}
\chapter{seven}
\chapter{six}
\chapter{seven}
\end{document}
```